# error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, cmake, teamcity

Собираю проект на TeamCity. Этот же проект на Jenkins собирается без проблем, а на TeamCity падает на нескольких json. Проект собирается с помощью cmake.

Win7_x64, Qt5.9.3, msvc2015_64

```
Running JSON RPC C++ compiler on C:/TC/work/169893a6ea1c5cd5/proj/Calc/res/Calculator.json
[14:02:33]C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515. [C:\TC\work\169893a6ea1c5cd5\Release_build\build\Calc.vcxproj]
[14:02:33]Done Building Project "C:\TC\work\169893a6ea1c5cd5\Release_build\build\Calc.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
```

При конфигурации все нормально.

Пути до библиотек тоже находит правильные. И все собирает, кроме json'ов.

В чем может быть проблема и куда копать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась все-так в окружении.
В глобальных параметрах Jenkins были объявлены дополнительные переменные, которые нужно было перенести на TeamCity.